# Facebook Sharer not giving Title

Tags: javascript, facebook, query-string, facebook-sharer

I have added a facebook button to my company's site so that people can quickly distribute surveys to users via facebook.  It is a pretty simple JavaScript:

```
function SFace()
{
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[[:SurveyUrl:]]","Facebook","width=700,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=0");
}

<img src="http://www.snap-surveys.com/test/face.jpg" onClick="SFace()" />
```

It works fine, but people want a customized title to appear.  So, I added &t=Something, however, when you click the link, it still just shows the long URL.  I thought maybe it was because I wasn't using encodeURIComponent.  So, I added a variable

```
var SFace="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[[:SurveyUrl:]]&t=something"; document.write(encodeURIComponent(uri));
```

And then using that in the function.  Same thing, shows the URL and not the title.  What exactly am I doing wrong?  How can I get it to show a custom title in the shared link?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this sharer.php thing is no longer supported and is deprecated.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ at the very top.

Comment: I just saw that.  I actually got the code from Joystiq.com, using their share button, which seems to have the &t field working correctly.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I tried to repro, but sharer.php wouldn't post to my wall ?! oh well.

Comment: So use the like plugin as the sharer.php is deprecated (meaning don't use it!!!)

Comment: Was able to find a work around using the dialog/feed?redirect_uri provided by facebook.  Will post when Stack allows me to answer my own question >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know my solution:

First needed to get an App ID from Facebook (get the developer's app, create a new app and set the URL as the base/common domain for the site with the button you are adding).  Once you have the ID  The URL is:

```
 http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feedredirect_uri=THE_URL&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&link=THE_URL_YOURE_LINKINGTO&name=TITLE_YOU_WANT_TO_DISPLAY
```

My recommendation is to write the full URL out like normal and create a variable with document.write(encodeURIComponent); like in my example above.  This will add the appropriate spacing characters.

If the URL matches the URL listed in the App, you can have a share link with a custom title and can therefore use your own button and not the default Like button that facebook provides.